# Is it safe to move a laptop in sleep or hibernate mode?

Tags: laptop, sleep, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to carry laptop around in sleep mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/104893/is-it-safe-to-carry-laptop-around-in-sleep-mode)

Is carrying a laptop when it is in hibernate or sleep mode safe?

Comment: I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate: the question here is about a PC (not a MAC) and it's about SLEEP mode OR HIBERNATE mode which are different in Windows OS PCs... HD protection when they are carried vary from PC models...

Comment: Then we'd need way more info from the OP. this post, as it stands, is too vague and doesn't really show research effort. @cli

Comment: That's right. :)