# What's the status of disk when computer sleeps?

Tags: operating-systems, sleep

What's the status of disk when computer sleeps? Is it safe to move the computer around?
And is there any difference between OS on sleeping behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when a computer goes to sleep?](http://superuser.com/questions/408737/what-happens-when-a-computer-goes-to-sleep), [Is it safe to carry laptop around in sleep mode?](http://superuser.com/questions/104893/is-it-safe-to-carry-laptop-around-in-sleep-mode) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the status of disk when computer sleeps? Is it safe to move the computer around?

Off, with the heads retracted naturally by the voice coils.

> And is there any difference between OS on sleeping behaviour?

Generally no.